# How do I make a Rust duration in hours without calculating it myself?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I using this code to do an interval in rust:

```
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut interval = time::interval(Duration::from_millis(10000));
    loop {
        interval.tick().await;

        println!("{}","trigger")
    }
}
```

When I want to set the interval to 1 hour, I have to write the Duration like this `1000 * 60 * 60`. is there any simple way just like `Duration::hours(1)`? I have tried `chrono` but seems it is not compatible with Tokio.

Comment: Hello, Duration::from_secs() exist or you can implement your solution inspired by the source https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/time.rs.html#210

Comment: There is [`from_secs`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/time/struct.Duration.html#method.from_secs) which only requires `60 * 60`, or you can use chrono and [`chrono::Duration::to_std`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/struct.Duration.html#method.to_std) to make it compatible with `tokio::time::interval`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extension trait to implement `hours()` on `Duration`

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time;

trait DurationExt {
    fn from_hours(hours: u64) -> Duration;
}

impl DurationExt for Duration {
    fn from_hours(hours: u64) -> Duration {
        Duration::from_secs(hours * 60 * 60)
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut interval = time::interval(Duration::from_hours(1));
    loop {
        interval.tick().await;

        println!("{}","trigger")
    }
}
```